# 405 method not allowed redirect error laravel why

Tags: php, laravel

my delete function like this:

help me guys before I added this line `return Redirect::route('attribute.index');`

I had no error but after I have this error

> 405 Method Not Allowed

```
public function update($id)
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $validator = Validator::make($input, CapacityModel::rules());

    // process the save
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        Session::flash('message', trans('messages.error_save'));
    } else {
        // store
        $this->capacity->update($input['capid'], $input);

        // redirect
        Session::flash('message', trans('messages.success_save'));
        return Redirect::route('attribute.index');
    }
}
```

my route like this:

```
Route::resource('/reference/attribute','nez\attribute\SeiAttributeController',['names'=>'attribute']);
```

my controller's index like this:

```
public function index()
{
    return View::make($this->view_path.'.index');
}
```

Comment: The methodNotAllowed exception indicates that a route doesn't exist for the HTTP method you are requesting.

Comment: Check your routes - php artisan route:list

Comment: Pls share the output of `php artisan route:list `

Answer (score 0):

This looks questionable:

```
  $this->capacity->update($input['capid'], $input);
```

Where does `$this->capacity` get resolved? Are you certain the attribute is always set at this point in the method?

The update method typically takes a single parameter, which is an array of keys with their new values.

If you have correctly resolved $this->capacity to the record you want to update, then you would be best off with something along these lines:

```
$this->capacity->update([
    'field_1' => Arr::get($input, 'field_1'),
    'field_2' => Arr::get($input, 'field_2'),
     //...etc
]);
```

Comment: see the answer below I had forgot to insert repository :)))